Django - NoReverseMatch at /carro/
I'm learning how to make a basic e-commerce site, but I have this problem that appears when I add a product in the cart. I tried everything (I think) but still can't make this cart to work.
It seems that the argument for "id_producto" is not reaching to nowhere.
URLS.PY
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from .import views

app_name = "carro"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.detalle_carro, name='detalle_carro'),
    path('add/<str:id_producto>/', views.carro_mas, name='carro_mas'),
    path('remove/<str:id_producto>/', views.carro_menos, name='remover_carro'),
]

VIEWS.PY
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from gestionPedidos.models import Producto
from .carro import Carro
from .forms import anadirProductoForm
#aqui va el form cupon

@require_POST
def carro_mas(request, id_producto):
    carro = Carro(request)
    producto = get_object_or_404(Producto, id_producto=id_producto)
    form = anadirProductoForm(request.POST)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        carro.anadir(producto = producto, cantidad=cd['cantidad'], update_cantidad=cd['update'])
    messages.success(request, "vamooo")
    return redirect('carro:detalle_carro')

def carro_menos(request, id_producto):
    carro = Carro(request)
    producto = get_object_or_404(Producto, id=id_producto)
    carro.remover(producto)
    return redirect('carro:detalle_carro')

def detalle_carro(request):
    carro = Carro(request)
    for item in carro:
        item['update_cantidad_form'] = anadirProductoForm(initial = {
            'cantidad' : item['cantidad'],
            'update' : True
        })
    return render(request, 'detalle_carro.html', {'carro' : carro})

my template
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Mi carrito de compras!{% endblock %}

{% block first_content %}
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
            <h1>Mi carrito de compras</h1>
            
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Remover</th>
                    <th>Precio unitario</th>
                    <th>Precio total</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for item in carro %}
                        {% with p=item.Producto %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {% if p.imagen %}
                                    <img class="img-afiche"  src="{{p.imagen.url}}" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="{{p.nombre}}">
                                    {% else %}
                                    <img src="{% static 'img/image_not_found.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="not found">
                                    {% endif %}                        
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h2>{{p.nombre}}</h2>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{% url 'carro:carro_mas' p.id_producto %}" method="post">
                                        {{ item.update_cantidad_form.cantidad}}
                                        {{ item.update_cantidad_form.update}}
                                        <input class='btn btn-default' type="submit" value="Actualizar">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                                <td><a href="{% url 'carro:carro_menos' p.id_producto %}">Remover</a></td>
                                <td> {{item.precio}} </td>
                                <td> {{item.precio_total}} </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endwith %}
                    {% endfor %}  
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align : right">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'home' %}">Seguir comprando</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}        

TRACEBACK
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/carro/

Django Version: 5.0.4
Python Version: 3.12.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'gestionPedidos',
 'carro']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\PP2024\ProyectoPortafolio2024\carro\templates\detalle_carro.html, error at line 35
   Reverse for 'carro_mas' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['carro/add/(?P<id_producto>[^/]+)/\\Z']
   25 :                                     {% if p.imagen %}
   26 :                                     <img class="img-afiche"  src="{{p.imagen.url}}" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="{{p.nombre}}">
   27 :                                     {% else %}
   28 :                                     <img src="{% static 'img/image_not_found.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="not found">
   29 :                                     {% endif %}                        
   30 :                                 </td>
   31 :                                 <td>
   32 :                                     <h2>{{p.nombre}}</h2>
   33 :                                 </td>
   34 :                                 <td>
   35 :                                     <form action=" {% url 'carro:carro_mas' p.id_producto %} " method="post">
   36 :                                         {{ item.update_cantidad_form.cantidad}}
   37 :                                         {{ item.update_cantidad_form.update}}
   38 :                                         <input class='btn btn-default' type="submit" value="Actualizar">
   39 :                                         {% csrf_token %}
   40 :                                     </form>
   41 :                                 </td>
   42 :                                 <td><a href="{% url 'carro:carro_menos' p.id_producto %}">Remover</a></td>
   43 :                                 <td> {{item.precio}} </td>
   44 :                                 <td> {{item.precio_total}} </td>
   45 :                             </tr>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\PP2024\ProyectoPortafolio2024\carro\views.py", line 34, in detalle_carro
    return render(request, 'detalle_carro.html', {'carro' : carro})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 25, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 159, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 242, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 549, in render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1000, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 479, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DUOC PORTAFOLIIO\amb\ambiente02\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 851, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /carro/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'carro_mas' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['carro/add/(?P<id_producto>[^/]+)/\\Z']

I expect the detalle_carro.html to render with the item product added.

it looks like you haven't changed your project's urls.py to include your carro app

Looks like the value for p.id_producto in the line <form action="{% url 'carro:carro_mas' p.id_producto %}" method="post"> is empty.
You might want to print that value and check.
Please also see this answer
